# Clicking on a link first time doesn't trigger jQuery, but clicking on it again triggers it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm having a bit of an issue. I have some links that when they are clicked run a function in jQuery, however, the first time I click the link nothing happens. If I click it again, the function runs twice, if I click it a third time, it runs three times off of that click.

Here is my jQuery code

```
function updateEntryStatus() {
    var anime_id = <?php echo $anime_id; ?>;
    var anime_list_entry_id = <?php echo $anime_list_entry_id; ?>;

        jQuery('.wantedStatus').on('click', function(event)
        {
                    var wantedStatus = jQuery(this).text();

                jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/sahifa/phanime_list/updateStatus_animelist.php", {firstParam : anime_id, secondParam : anime_list_entry_id, thirdParam : wantedStatus}, function(data) {
                //this is your response data from serv
                console.log(data);
                                jQuery('#anime_list_update').html(data);

            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

and here are a couple of my links

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="updateEntryStatus();" class="wantedStatus">Watching</a> | 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="updateEntryStatus();" class="wantedStatus">Plan to watch</a> | 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="updateEntryStatus();" class="wantedStatus">On hold</a> | 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="updateEntryStatus();" class="wantedStatus">Dropped</a>
```

Example:

Click 1: Nothing happens

Click 2: function runs twice.

Click 3: function runs 3 times / in total runs 5 times.

Click 4: function runs 4 times / in total run 9 times
and so on...

I am assuming is it's the way i've setup the click within my function.

Comment: You are adding a new click handler every time you call updateEntryStatus().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take this

```
                    jQuery('.wantedStatus').on('click', function(event)
                    {
                        var wantedStatus = jQuery(this).text();

                            jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/sahifa/phanime_list/updateStatus_animelist.php", {firstParam : anime_id, secondParam : anime_list_entry_id, thirdParam : wantedStatus}, function(data) {
                                //this is your response data from serv
                            console.log(data);
                            jQuery('#anime_list_update').html(data);

                        });
                            return false;
                    });
                }
```

part out of your updateEntryStatus() function.

Comment: Then I should remove the onclick call from the links? If I do, will the links still work properly?

Comment: when you add the remaining code from your updateEntryStatus() function to the jquery click trigger it should work

Answer (score 1):

You don't setup the `onclick` event until someone has clicked on the link. Each time they click on the link you setup another event handler.

Move the `jQuery('.wantedStatus').on('click', function(event)` call outside of the `updateEntryStatus()` function and ensure the `.on()` function is called before someone clicks on the link.